# extracting id from url user input in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i would like to extract part of a url and not sure what is the best practice for going about that. the url input format would be like: `https://somesite.com/video/123456` i would like to extract the video id which is `123456`so i can use at another place. any thoughts or suggestion would be appreciated. I am not sure how to use a `split` or if using `regex` would be better.

Comment: Is it always in this format?  `split('/')` would give you what you need if it doesn't change.

Comment: After reading about [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) you'll know ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your URL format is consitent just use the following

```js
var url  =  "https://somesite.com/video/123456";

var id = url.split("/")[4]
```

Comment: I'd recommend adding a general solution as well, not just the specific one. Something like this `var id = window.location.href.split('?')[0].split('/').pop();`